# Way to produce a table in pandas given a formula and zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following df:

```
Letter    Number
  a         0
  b         0
  c         0 
  d         1
  e         2
  f         3
```

I want to apply the following formula to the df

```
for i in range(1,len(df):
  x = df.loc[i,'Number'] /df.loc[i-1,'Number'] + df.loc[i,'Number']
  df.loc[i,'Number'] = x
```

Note: The column 'Number' only has zeros in the first few rows. After, there are no more zeros.

How would I apply the formula to the df without slicing the zeros off?

Comment: Use `apply` on the dataframe

Comment: Can you add expected output to the question too?

Comment: if you want to get the value of the previous and next rows, you can use `df['Number'].shift()` and `df['Number'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate @bigbounty

Comment: @JoeFerndz that helps but since we are dividing by zero, I will still get an error.

Comment: As @bigbounty said, you need to use apply and check if any of the values are 0 before you divide by 0

Comment: What is the expected output ?  Once I understand what the expected output is, I can help you with the apply statement

Comment: It would be 0,0,0,1,4,4.5 Thank you! @JoeFerndz

Comment: Ok. I have posted my response. Pablo's solution is also good to consider.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the previous row's number by using [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html). Then you can compute the value using the formula you defined. For that we can use [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Here's how we can do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter':list('abcdef'),'Number':[0,0,0,1,2,3]})
print (df)

# capture the previous row's value
df['Prev'] = df.Number.shift()

# check if prev row value is NaN or 0. It will be NaN for first row
# if Nan or 0, don't divide instead use 0. Then add current row value
df['New'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Number + ((x.Number/x.Prev) if (pd.isnull(x.Prev) or x.Prev !=0) else 0), axis = 1)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be (Prev is the previous row; New is the computed result):

```
  Letter  Number  Prev  New
0      a       0   NaN  NaN
1      b       0   0.0  0.0
2      c       0   0.0  0.0
3      d       1   0.0  1.0
4      e       2   1.0  4.0
5      f       3   2.0  4.5
```

If you want the first row to have a value of 0, we can modify the .shift() option a bit and fillna(0). That will make the first row value to be 0. You can drop the `Prev` column after the computation.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet divides, using [`pd.Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html), the Series `Number` by the [`shifted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) values of `Number` and then adds `Number` using [`pd.Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)

```py
>>> df.Number.div(df.Number.shift()).add(df.Number)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    inf
4    4.0
5    4.5
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```